# Is it possible to <br> every 10 table rows in CSS?

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

My script basically loads data from my database and I have to `<br>` somewhere but it wont work because its a huge table. So I need to format this table so every 10 rows there is a `<br>`.

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <?php
        $date = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `matches`"); 
        while($daterow = mysql_fetch_assoc($date)){

            echo '  <tr>
                    <td style="width:60px; background-color:#000000;"><font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:11px">'.$daterow['date'].'</font></td>
                    </tr>
                ';

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT hour, team1, team2, goalsteam1, goalsteam2, competition FROM `matches` WHERE `date`='". $daterow['date'] ."'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    

                $teamtest = mysql_query("SELECT teamname FROM `teams` WHERE `team`='".$row['team1']."'");
                $teamtestrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($teamtest);

                $hour = substr($row['hour'],0,5);

                echo '
                    <tr class="teamtable">
                        <td style="width:60px; font-size:11px;">'.$hour.'</td>
                        <td style="width:145px; font-size:11px;">'.$teamrow['teamtest'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:15px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['goalsteam1'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:15px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['goalsteam2'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:145px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['team2'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:120; font-size:11px;">'.$row['competition'].'</td>
                    </tr>'; 
            }
        }
    ?>  
</table>
```

Or just `<br>` before every date. When I tried it will just leave a huge blank space up but still no space between the date and matches.

Comment: `for '<br>' in $half-assed-question { print 'calm down and spell out the details'; }`

Comment: If you mean a `<table>`, then no. `<br>`s aren't valid between the `<tr>`s of an HTML table. Though, you can place an empty row -- `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`.

Comment: Yeah.. just figured out I can place a blank row.. ty..

Comment: Um... HTML is not CSS.  This question has nothing to do with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure if CSS can handle this. And unclear on where you expect a break to occur based on the code you are sharing. But in general you would use the [modulus](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator in PHP would be a good start. Knowing that maybe this would work for you:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <?php
        $date = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `matches`"); 
        $counter = 0;
        while($daterow = mysql_fetch_assoc($date)){

            echo '  <tr>
                    <td style="width:60px; background-color:#000000;"><font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:11px">'.$daterow['date'].'</font></td>
                    </tr>
                ';

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT hour, team1, team2, goalsteam1, goalsteam2, competition FROM `matches` WHERE `date`='". $daterow['date'] ."'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    

                $teamtest = mysql_query("SELECT teamname FROM `teams` WHERE `team`='".$row['team1']."'");
                $teamtestrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($teamtest);

                $hour = substr($row['hour'],0,5);

                echo '
                    <tr class="teamtable">
                        <td style="width:60px; font-size:11px;">'.$hour.'</td>
                        <td style="width:145px; font-size:11px;">'.$teamrow['teamtest'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:15px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['goalsteam1'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:15px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['goalsteam2'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:145px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['team2'].'</td>
                        <td style="width:120; font-size:11px;">'.$row['competition'].'</td>
                    </tr>'; 

                $counter++;
                // Do a modulus check.
                if ($counter % 10 == 0) {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>  
</table>
```

The key chunk of code is this:

```
$counter++;
// Do a modulus check.
if ($counter % 10 == 0) {
    echo "<tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
```

On each loop `$counter` is incremented by 1. And using the modulus operator in the `if()` statement we check for every 10th item & then do something. In this case insert a row with an `&nbsp;` in it.